# Program & Clocking Block Rules in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In program block, we can't give non-blocking assignment to any of the variable. If we try to do it, it shows error like "Program variable: d can only be assigned using blocking assignments".

Similarly, in clocking block, if we try to assign it using blocking assignment then it shows the error like "Clocking block output cb1.d signal must be driven by a non-blocking assignment".

What is the reason behind these rules??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend using program blocks - they are a massive source of confusion and completely unnecessary. Check out one of my more popular [blog posts](http://go.mentor.com/programblocks).

To answer your first question, the rule about not being able to use NBAs to program variables was eliminated long ago. You must not be using a recent version of software.

To answer your second question, clocking block outputs use drive statements which are different from blocking and nonblocking assignments. See section *14.16.1 Drives and nonblocking assignments* in the [1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).

Comment: Yes may be I am using older version of compiler. I have read the LRM and now understood the difference between nonblocking and synchronous drive. But I don't able to find out any possible reasons for not allowing blocking statements in clocking block.

Comment: You can only use the `<=` operator to make an assignment to a clocking block `output`variable in a clocking block. You are not allow to use a clocking block output for anything else. You can't even read it in an expression.

Comment: I wonder if we'll ever get a revision of the 1800 with features removed or do we have to wait for the next big thing(tm)?